# File not found exception when using ShapefileFeatureTable with ArcGIS on Android

Tags: android, arcgis, arcgis-android-api

I'm trying to use `ArcGIS` to draw some shape file on the map using its `ShapefileFeatureTable`. But when I try the load the shape file I get a `File not found` Exception.
This is the code I'm using:

```
ShapefileFeatureTable shapefileFeatureTable;
try {
    shapefileFeatureTable = new ShapefileFeatureTable(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/shape.shp");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "loading shape failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

The catch here is that the shape file actually exists on the sdcard. I debugged the code and reached this part which is throwing the exception:

```
static Geodatabase a(String var0) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File var1 = new File(var0);
    if(!var1.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(var1 + " does not exist.");
    } else {
        return new Geodatabase(nativeOpenShapefile(var0)); // this is where it happens
    }
}
```

The native `nativeOpenShapefile` seems to not be able to see the file while the java part perfectly sees it. Check the stacktrace:

> D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib
>   /data/data/com.hmomeni.arcgis/lib/libruntimecore_java.so 0x4163daf0
>   D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib
>   /data/data/com.hmomeni.arcgis/lib/libruntimecore_java.so 0x4163daf0
>   W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Shape file not found:
>   /storage/sdcard0/shape.shp W/System.err:     at
>   com.esri.core.geodatabase.Geodatabase.nativeOpenShapefile(Native
>   Method) W/System.err:     at
>   com.esri.core.geodatabase.Geodatabase.a(SourceFile:126) W/System.err: 
>   at
>   com.esri.core.geodatabase.ShapefileFeatureTable.(SourceFile:79)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.hmomeni.arcgis.MainActivity.initView(MainActivity.java:32)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.hmomeni.arcgis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5031) W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4797)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:543)
>   W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I wonder what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I have not included all the necessary files that come with `.shp` file. There are other files needed for this purpose such as `.shx`, `.dbf`, `.prj`.
Including them all fixed the issue.

Comment: @aah134 I remember just putting there along with `.shp` file was enough.

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml, did you request permission to read and/or write the external storage?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Try each of those and see if it helps. See [the ArcGIS Runtime documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/install-and-set-up.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C9913E8160D74241977115BEA470E1C3) and read the section "Required permissions and features" for details.